# How can I build a file-upload POST HTTP request with WebOb?

Tags: python, http, testing, wsgi, webob

I am using Ian Bicking's WebOb to very great effect in writing Python web application tests. I call `webob.Request.blank('/path...')`, and then use the resulting request object's `get_response(app)` method to invoke my web application. The response object that is returned lets me check the HTTP response's status code, content type, body, and so forth. Building a POST request is also quite easy:

```
Request.blank('/path/under/test/', POST={'query': 'some text'})
```

But now I have run across a bit of a puzzle: I need to test a view in my web application that expects a file upload, and I cannot quite figure out how WebOb represents that particular kind of POST. Does anyone know how to build a WebOb request with one or more file-upload fields inside?

Answer (score 5):

As of a couple days ago you can do:

```
req = Request.blank('/path/under/test', 
                    POST={'query': 'some text', 'upload': ('filename', 'content')})
```

This was brought in [in this commit](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/webob/changeset/5c47c010138f), and has not yet been released.

Comment: A perfect-but-unreleased answer that would make the operation simple beyond my wildest imaginings! And also a new situation for me: do I dangle the Big Green Checkmark as incentive for you to release? Or go ahead and accept the answer and grumpily run WebOb from trunk on this project? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebTest](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/) for that, see this `TestApp.post` arguments [here](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/#making-requests).